# I just started learning React native . I just "TypeError: Cannot read property 'transformFile' of undefined"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, expo

I just started learning React native .
I just set up react native expo and creates my first project. But while creating an Android app it's throw error
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'transformFile' of undefined"

Please help me
I tried removing node modules ,package lock json still no useb

I tried removing node modules and lock json, remove it and re install nothing use .

Answer (score 0):

First, delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and receive the `npm install` again

There is an attempt to downgrade `NodeJS` to the LTS version.

Use `nvm` to manage `NodeJs` versions.